# How to make text not disappear if player walks throught 2 colliders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have 2 colliders and text placed close to each other

I made the text appear when I enter the colliders with this code:

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    switch (col.gameObject.name) 
    {
        case "boxTopCups":
            interactionText.SetActive(true);
            break;
        case "boxTopSlicedCucumber":
            interactionText.SetActive(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

And disapper with this code:

```
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    switch (col.gameObject.name)
    {
        case "boxTopCups":
            interactionText.SetActive(false);
            break;
        case "boxTopSlicedCucumber":
            interactionText.SetActive(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

But when player goes from first the colliders to second the text disapers. How to make it not disapper when player goes from one collider to another?

Comment: if you player bypass first collider (enter and then exit) it will collapse due to you code. Best way would be to save position of those colliders and player's position, so you could check at witch direction you character moved, in direction of second collider or in opposite direction. If it will go at opposite direction you will save all code as is, but if you player will move in direction of second collider, you need to disable at 'OnTriggerExit2D' one of the cases, so when player left first collider it wouldn't disable your text. But the best case would be using a single colider for a space.

Comment: why not you use `OnTriggerStay2D` ,then if it is not in collider it will hide the text

Comment: @Tengku thanks a lot